# Getting error using mvn spring-boot:run "A child container fail to start"

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

If I am run using my spring tool suites, then it's working fine, but while running using command prompt **mvn spring-boot:run** I am getting these error:

```
8564: ERROR ContainerBase - A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the sa
ackage
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:895) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:665) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4752) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
8564: ERROR ContainerBase - A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:344) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:89) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.j
.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1
.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.
:384) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:1
[spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159) [spring-boot-1.2
ELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.
ASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474) [spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RE
E]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:690) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:970) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:959) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at com.hm.msp.event.EventHubServer.main(EventHubServer.java:23) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
8564: WARN  AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.
icationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to st
embedded Tomcat
8564: ERROR SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServlet
ainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8
EASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474) ~[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.R
SE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:690) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:970) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:959) [spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at com.hm.msp.event.EventHubServer.main(EventHubServer.java:23) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) ~[spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.
1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:
8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.
:384) ~[spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:1
~[spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-1.
RELEASE.jar:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar:1.2.8
EASE]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.2.8.RELEASE.
1.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.Embe
ServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:690)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:970)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:959)
        at com.hm.msp.event.EventHubServer.main(EventHubServer.java:23)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.
:384)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:1
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:344)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:89)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 24 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.858 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-16T16:33:40+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 50M/521M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project core.eventhub: An exception occurred while run
. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Un
 to start embedded Tomcat: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[
at]]: A child container failed during start -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is the pom.xml I am using ,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hm.msp.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample.springboot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>sample-server</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Angel.SR6</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.hm.msp.event.Main</start-class>
        <mstack.version>2.0.1</mstack.version>
        <json-lib.version>2.4</json-lib.version>
        <msp.blp.version>0.2.0</msp.blp.version>
        <msp.collection.version>2.0.1</msp.collection.version>
        <msp.bundle.version>0.2.0</msp.bundle.version>
        <camel.version>2.17.0</camel.version>
        <xbean-spring-version>4.5</xbean-spring-version>
        <!--following activemq version has dependencies. If you upgrade activemq 
            libs make sure to pick up the right version -->
        <activemq-version>5.11.1</activemq-version>
        <activemq-pool-version>5.7.0</activemq-pool-version>
        <logback-version>1.1.3</logback-version>
        <storm.version>0.10.0</storm.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <!-- <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Testing starter -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Data JPA Repository support -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger dependency for mIDAS webservice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>${storm.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the culprit

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

First, don't put `version`with Spring Boot, it is taking care to bring the right version for the things it manage. Then you're forcing an incompatible (old) servlet API, leading to that exception.

Comment: Hi ,After removing servlet-api ,also I am getting same error .Any other suggestion .

Comment: swagger, maybe? Just run `mvn dependency:list -Dsort` and look for an outdated servlet dependency in the output.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem. In addition to removing direct dependency 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5' (as suggested by @Stephane Nicoll), you also need to exclude it from the dependencies that includes 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
Following command is handy to find where it is coming from
`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=javax.servlet`
That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue, and after removing version from javax.servlet dependency it worked fine.